# Remove tabBar from view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a tab bar app w/ the following drill down flow:
view 1 > view 2 > view 3 > view 4

I'd like to remove the tab bar from view 2 and keep the tab bar on views 1, 3 and 4.

I tried setting the code below when loading view 2.
vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

The code successfully removes the tab bar on view 2, but I can't get the tab bar to come back on views 3 and 4.  I assumed I'd be able to set YES to NO (vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;) when views 3 and 4 are selected to bring back the tab bar, but that doesn't work.

How can I remove the tab bar on view 2 only (keep the tab bar on views 1, 3 and 4)?

Answer (score 2):

Overwrite the init function (loadView probably won't work) for views 3 and 4 and set

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

That should work.